# Bueno estoy intentando hacer un CRUD y tengo problemas

Tags: php, html, css, postgresql, crud

Ya me funciono el crear datos y mostrar datos, pero no se por que no me funciona el de actualizar datos les voy a mostrar mi código y lo q me sale.
[image: Como pueden ver me sale "Undefined array key"]

[image: Aca esta el codigo de update]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando cambio var_dump($_GET) por var_dump($datosFinales) me sale lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eso es todo, espero una respuesta.

Comment: 3 cosas: 1. ¡Te doy la bienvenida a SOes! 2. Recuerda realizar el recorrido para ver el funcionamiento del sitio y del mismo modo, obtendrás tu primera medalla (https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). 3. Aquí una serie de sugerencias de cómo preguntar: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te está pasando es lógico.
A la hora de escribir los valores que recoges de la BDD no estás utilizando `$datosFinales`, sino un array `$row` que no existe y que no has definido en ningún lado.

Cambia los `$row` por `$datosFinales` y prueba.

Comment: Hola gracias responder, ya organice lo q no funciona y ya me funciona bien todo gracias